# Using CustomValidator on 2 controls asp.net javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, controls, client-side-validation, customvalidator

I am having an issue generating a pop up warning box when validating the weight entered.
I have a text box that the user enters the numeric weight and a drop down menu that they select if the unit of measure(UOM) is in TONS, LBS, Kilograms, etc; this is done in asp.net. 
I have a javascript function on the same design page that if the weight entered is greater than 900 tons (or the lbs and kilogram equivalent) a javascript confirm 'ok' or 'cancel' pop up appears. For quick example:
if (uom.value == "TONS" && weight.value > 900) {confirm('Are you sure?'}

I was having an issue where if they entered the numeric weight and THEN changed the unit of measure drop down, the pop up would not appear; it only worked if they selected the UOM and then entered the value. This is because in my "CustomValidator" the 'ControlToValidate" was the weight textbox. I did some research and tried not specifying a "controltovalidate" but this caused it not to work at all. So my work around was to add a second CustomValidator who's 'controlToValidate" was the UOM drop down, but used the same ValidateWeight function for the ClientValidationFunction.

This all works EXCEPT because I now have 2 customValidators using the same function, I receive the pop up confirmation box twice, i.e. I click cancel and I get the box again and have to click cancel a second time.

This seems like such a simple problem but I just cannot figure it out. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: In a case like this I'd recommend writing custom validation in JavaScript.

Comment: I do have a custom validation function in Javascript but I still need the CUstomValidator. I just use the ClientValidationFunction property to call my JS function